# idRepo filesize slowly growing to large

Tags: java, openam

Currently im working on a project with a customer where we use openAm. We have however noticed that the idRepo file is slowly growing in size. Even though its growing slowly its already reaching 120Gb on some places where space is becoming increasingly limited. We have some documentation mentioning that whenever idRepo reaches such huge filesizes you need to adjust some settings in the debugconfig.properties file which is found in our:

```
installationDirectory\OpenAM\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\OpenAM-12.0.0\WEB-INF\classes directory
```

The documentation mentioned is found here:
(https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/sso90/Debug+log+files)

From what i could understand from that page is that i have to add:

```
org.forgerock.openam.debug.prefix=debug
org.forgerock.openam.debug.suffix='.'u'.log'
org.forgerock.openam.debug.rotation=1440
org.forgerock.openam.debug.history.files.count=7
```

to the debugconfig.properties file, which I did. We also, as noted in the documentation stopped and started the server. This happened 2 days ago as off writing this. The filesize however has not changed. Now here comes some inexperience on my part as i have close to zero knowledge of openAm and no clue what idRepo is. After googling i couldnt find a proper answer to this issue. I would expect that a log file is created every day since i added the rotation setting. The log folder is empty though. Now this is currently taking place on our develop/test server so the problem there isnt huge. But if we cant fix it on these servers we cant fix it on the PRODUCTION server which will slowly work towards a crash in that manner.

My collegues don't know the answer to this problem and with the limited documentation (or my lack of understanding it) I was hoping someone on stackOverflow could give me a better answer and/or solution.

If information is missing I will gladly add it where possible.
Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: 12-02-2018
I have been keeping tabs on whether the filesize has been growing or not and i can state that the the test environment it isnt (This is where i have been making adjustments according to the answers)
On the other 2 environments one being production the filesize is indeed growing slowly but surely. If i check the properties on the test environment it will tell me the last modification has been done 3 januari 2017. If i check it on either of the other 2 environments it will tell me the adjustment was done the very second i opened properties (to the second exact). The debugproperties file containing:

```
org.forgerock.openam.debug.prefix=debug
org.forgerock.openam.debug.suffix='.'u'.log'
org.forgerock.openam.debug.rotation=1440
org.forgerock.openam.debug.history.files.count=7
```

was also adjusted 3 januari 2017. This would make me believe that using these settings will prevent the idRepo file from growing any further than it has done till this point. If someone could verify that for me  that would be great (im gonna test it in the acceptation enviroment on my own before i move to production).

Once again i would like to thank you guys for the quick replies and the help! If you need more information feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening in a dev environment, chances are that you have configured your OpenAM instance with message level debug log mode. To check the debug log level, you should go to Configuration -> Servers and sites -> Default Server (and/or each Server in the list individually) -> General tab.

The fix should be to change the debug level to error, as it is less verbose, and less likely to cause disk space issues.

I should also point out that the referenced `org.forgerock.openam.debug.history.files.count` setting does not actually exist as far as I can tell. The rolled over debug log files are never removed by OpenAM to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, i've set the logging level to error now (was OFF). Should i now slowly see the idRepo file decrease in size? Would it be wise to add the expire time setting to my properties though? or would that also negatively impact the query?

Comment: If it was turned off, then error level will only result in more logs, and you shouldn't have had an IdRepo debug log at all. The files won't decrease in size and won't disappear either. If you want to get rid of them, you will need to delete them manually. The expiration setting only makes sense when the cache itself is enabled, however it will still result in more queries than just simply having the cache enabled without expiration.

Comment: If it was turned off then the problem may have not been related to logging at all.

Comment: One thing to add, in the past few days where i have been paying attention i haven't seen the idRepo file grow in size either. So maybe its something left over from people using different settings? Even with the logging set to ERROR now the idRepo isn't growing in size. I don't know if this info helps though.

Answer (score -1):

This is a guess since I have less [OpenAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAM) knowledge than you (i.e., none), but I'm including it as an answer as it's too long for a comment.

I found a document entitled [Tune Caches in OpenAM](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Tune+Caches+in+OpenAM) in ForgeRock's Confluence pages. It mentions some settings different from the ones you list above.

In particular, I believe you can disable idRepo caching by setting:

```
com.iplanet.am.sdk.caching.enabled=false
com.sun.identity.sm.cache.enabled=true
com.sun.identity.idm.cache.enabled=false
```

(This exact combination of settings does not appear in the document, but it is implied by the other combinations they show.)

There is also a maximum size setting for the idRepo cache:

> Property: com.iplanet.am.sdk.cache.maxSize
>
> The size of the IdRepo cache may be adjusted with this property.  By default this cache will contain up to 10,000 entries.  Note that there is no equivalent property to control the size of the SMS cache.

There are also settings related to expiring entries from the idRepo cache based on time-to-live. I am just going to copy that section of the document here verbatim:

> Property: com.sun.identity.idm.cache.entry.expire.enabled
> Property: com.sun.identity.idm.cache.entry.default.expire.time
>
> These properties control whether the IdRepo cache will expire entries based on time-to-live and how old entries may get before expiring.  By default the enabled property is False and the expire.time is 30 (the latter is expressed in minutes).
>
> Property: com.sun.identity.sm.cache.ttl.enable
> Property: com.sun.identity.sm.cache.ttl
>
> These properties control whether the SMS cache will expire entries based on time-to-live and set the maximum time-to-live value.  By default these properties are false and 30 minutes respectively.  The TTL value is expressed in minutes.
>
> In busy systems significant performance gains can be achieved by extending these time-to-live values but this must be balanced against the change rate of the underlying data.  User data (IdRepo cache) typically changes at a much higher rate than OpenAM configuration data so the IdRepo TTL should be kept relatively low while SMS TTL may be much higher.

There is more, but I hesitate to copy it all over here. I suspect that setting the maximum size or time-to-live might help with your problem, or possibly even turning the cache off and back on again might clear out the old entries (I have no idea, and don't know whether you would want to).

Again, I have no experience with OpenAM and offer this only as something that I managed to Google in the hopes it might help. It does give me a bit of pause that the settings you mentioned are all `org.forgerock` whereas these are `com.iplanet` and `com.sun`, which makes me wonder if this documentation is out of date, but it may just recapitulate the history of the development of [OpenAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAM), which began its life as a Sun Microsystems project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the incredibly quick comment. I've adjusted the settings and read the document you posted (good info in there) restarted the server again and not too sure on whether it has worked or not. The idRepo file is still huge and i have no clue if i can delete it without breaking stuff. I will keep an eye on the filesize in the hopes of seeing it decline anytime soon.

Comment: Although this answer is very detailed and mostly accurate, unfortunately it is also quite misleading given that it is likely to make the log situation even worse than before. The purpose of the caching is to ensure that there are less requests being made to the user data store (aka idrepo), so by disabling the IDM cache, effectively the idrepo will be queried a *lot* more often, resulting in even more log statements.

Comment: @Peter I wasn't advocating turning the cache off, only providing information on the settings. I just mentioned turning the cache off and back on as one possible thing to try. Also, it's not clear in the question if it's the logging or the cache itself taking up the space. J.Gieskens says "the idRepo file is slowly growing in size."

Comment: Given that the cache is in-memory, the IdRepo file can only mean the debug logs in my opinion.

Comment: The reason i called the title "slowly growing in size" was that we were receiving complaints from another team that the desktop was running out of space. That was making me assume that it wasnt a problem before this and it wasnt as big as before. I however cant really confirm this right now. I'm going to see if i can find some history in the file.